# What query can i use to get subcategories for each category?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I am using this query to get the children of each category

```
$this['children'] = Cat::first()->children;
```

But it only gets the subcategories of of the first category and the same subcategories appear for all other categories. Any ideas on how t fix this?

Model relation

```
 public function children(){

    return $this->hasMany(static::class,'parent_id','id');
```

Table structure

category table

id

cat_title

parent_id

nest_right

nest_left

nest_depth

slug

parent_id = 0(category)

parent_id > 0(subcategory)

Comment: Can you show your  Model relations and table structure?

Comment: you need to use eager load using `with`, `Cat::with('children')->get();`

Comment: How do i iterate through them to get subcats belonging to each cat? cos now it gets all the cats and attached subcats

Answer (score 1):

To get sub-categories of each category you first need to get the id of each category and use it in you query. (e.g. in a foreach loop)

```
$this['children'] = Cat::find($id)->children;
```

If you need to get all the categories with their related subcategories at the same time you need to eager load:

```
$allCatsWithTheirChildren = Cat::with('children')->all();
```

Comment: thanks the first option is what i want but it throws up Undefined variable: id, i know i am suppose to define that. Not sure how with what i have tried.

Comment: In your code "$this['children'] = ..." what's $this? Is that Category model? or that's another class you use in your code?

Comment: Yeah, Category Model

Comment: Ok, so in that case just $children = $this->children; should work. Because you already have the children relation in your model and you could just use that.

Comment: No, it didn't. It just came up empty

Comment: It's more helpful if you could share your Model, View and Controller code. Also the variable $children I used, is just an example, in your code it may be like this: $this['children'] = $this->children;

Comment: I decided to eager load it. So now all the subs show up. With this i am told i can easily iterate through them with 2 foreach loops. How to accomplish that is what i am trying out because for now, i only have one foreach loop

Comment: What's the variable your foreach loop iterating? I think the problem comes from the actual place you're using the array $this['children']. I mean you don't need $this['children'] and you don't need to assign anything to it, you can just use $this->children anywhere in your Model you like.